# Wireless to wireless (wireless server) terrible network performance

Tags: router, wifi

I have a server on a totally wireless network.  PCs frequently disconnect and access to the server such as SQL query's and file transfers are painfully slow.

**Wireless to Wireless**

```
PCs <-wireless-> WIRELESS_ROUTER <-wireless-> SERVER
```

I have a cheap Hauwei wireless router but my guess is that the 'Wireless to Wireless' configuration is a terrible idea.

My plan is to buy decent router and connect that router to the server via cable:

**Wireless to Cable**

```
PCs <-wireless-> WIRELESS_ROUTER <-cable-> SERVER
```

*Note: PCs must be wireless because they sit on carts and in constant movement.*

I am not knowledgeable in networking but using the server to cable model should mean a 50% reduction in WiFi traffic, which should translate to:

- less latency (higher speed)
- less network errors (greater reliability)

I am really hoping to get some thoughts from someone with experience in networking/wireless before I go through the expense of having wire laid out and buying a new router.  Maybe there is a better way to accomplish this.  Please keep in mind that the stand-alone server does not require access to the internet or to other devices other than the PCs.

**P.S.**  I read that TCP is a 'stateful' protocol, meaning that it keeps a connection alive.  Software on the PCs is TCP based.  What happens is that they frequently disconnect from the server and sometimes it is a pain to re-establish connections, e.g. server software must be restarted in worse case scenarios.  I also read that TCP was originally designed for wired networks and that on wireless networks, 'random bit error' rates are high.  The fact that I am dealing with double wifi (wireless to wireless) is probably the root of my problems.  Does this seem like a logical analysis?

**UPDATE**

I connected to the server via telnet and ran some queries many times.  There is a noticeable but acceptable network latency.  After about 100 queries, I got the following error (via telnet):

```
The semaphore timeout period has expired
```

I am quite convinced that this 'wireless to wireless' configuration is a bad idea overall.  Next week I will have the server wired directly to the router.  My guess is that this will cut latency by 50% and decrease network errors by even a greater margin.

Comment: You didn't say the type of equipment and range used, or the number of PCs powered by this system. There are many things to consider here, so some details are required.

Comment: A completely wireless network without pro level wireless gear attempting to process SQL queries is a recipe for problems. If the PCs must be wireless, the server absolutely must be wired to the switch/router to provide at least some level of network consistency.

Comment: @DanBig, I do believe that you are correct, but just wondering if you've experimented with a wireless server?  I'm going to suggest this potential solution to my boss because it seems very logical, of course, I hope that it makes a big difference so that I don't look bad.

Comment: A wireless server simply isn't a good idea, I really can't think of any pros to it.